# how do i get the mixlr radio stream to play in android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to get a mixlr streaming radio in an android app to play.

Problem is this (using ShoutCast as an example): If I have the IP address, I can get the stream to play in an embedded player in an Android app (I have a separate app for someone that uses ShoutCast and it worked).

However, for mixlr, it seems that you can only embed the radio in a web page and not a mobile app (???). If I am wrong please, help me.

The IP address for mixlr.com is 54.247.112.250. However, this does not point to the specific radio (I need a port number - I do believe?).

By the way - I did not include code because I am asking for a general advice and I am assuming that the approach used for shoutcast radios will work the same here. I am asking if anyone has gotten it to work with mixlr streaming internet radios and what they did.

Thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually talked the person into using another service with a well know API for Android.
Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a Stream URL from Mixlr, you need to subscribe to their Mixlr Pro plan.  As stated on their Pricing Chart, that comes with "Your own livestream URL."

Pricing Chart: https://mixlr.com/priceplans/

Once you have that plan, your stream URL will be http://edge.mixlr.com/channel/XXXXX

The Xs represent your unique stream ID.

Comment: New url: `http://mixlr.com/USERNAME/embed/` or `http://mixlr.com/users/USERCODE/embed/` "USERNAME" is pro version, USERCODE is for common user.